# How to detect if a string contains atleast one char of a particular language?

Tags: java, android, string, unicode

I am creating an Android application where I have a string. I want to check whether this string contains at least one character that belongs to Hindi language or not.

It does not matter in which language the String is, but if it has atleast one character that is in Hindi language, my function needs to be called.

One of the ways of doing so is comparing each character of the string with all the unicodes of Hindi language. But wont that be too time consuming? For example 50 character of string and 50 unicode will end up with 2500 comparisons already.

What can be the most optimum solution to this?

Comment: do you want to check only that input language is not English or not?

Comment: No. I have a String. I want to check if it contains any character that belongs to Hindi language or not. The rest of the string can be anything.

Comment: Here I found something that is supposed to print all hindi chars.
https://milindjagre.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/how-to-print-hindi-characters-using-java/comment-page-1/

So think that if you go through the entire input String and check if the char is between the two numbers 2309 and 2360, you can get the job done with 2n comparisions (with n being the String length).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think of these two methods

**Method 1**

```
 boolean isHindi = false;
 for (char c: myString.toCharArray()) {
     if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.DEVANAGARI) {
         isHindi = true;
         break;
     }
 }
```

**Method 2**

```
    boolean isHindi = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < Character.codePointCount(myString, 0, myString.length()); k++) {
        int c = myString.codePointAt(k);
        if (c >= 0x0900 && c <= 0x097F) {  //Hindi uni-codes are within this range
            isHindi = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didnt get the part `Character.UnicodeBlock.DEVANAGARI` What If I want to check with other languages too? Not sure how would I change it if I had to do the same with other languages. Well I guess your second method is more intuitive to me.

Comment: Almost all major languages are contain in `Character.UnicodeBlock` set such as Arbic, Gujarati, Bengali, Hebrew etc. Use can use `||(or)` to check multiple language. Look at :- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html

Comment: got it! thanks, and so you turn out to be Gujarati too. Nice

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java-8, you could do:

```
boolean isHindi = 
    myString.chars().anyMatch(c -> Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.DEVANAGARI);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do regex matching. Here is a sample code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HindiDetctionDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Pattern hindiFirstCharMatchPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\u0900-\\u097F].*");
        Matcher hindiFirstCharMatcher = hindiFirstCharMatchPattern.matcher("ok ");
        if(hindiFirstCharMatcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("could not find.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note about regex

`[\u0900-\u097F]` is matcher for hindi characters.

`.*` is appended so that matching stops after first match.